# Decimal value in form wont validate Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Here's my form i am trying to user to pass two char fields and two coordinates so they can be turned into objects. I just figured out the validation on the char fields, but now the decimal fields wont work. Any suggestions?

```
from django import forms


class SubmitForm(forms.Form):
title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
story = forms.CharField(max_length=3000)
lat = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)
lng = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)

def clean_title(self):  
    if len(self.cleaned_data['title']) < 4:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your full title")
    # Always return the cleaned data
    return self.cleaned_data['title']


def clean_story(self):
    if len(self.cleaned_data['story']) < 4:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your full story")
    # Always return the cleaned data
    return self.cleaned_data['story']

def clean_lng(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['lng'] == 0.0:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your full story")    
    return self.cleaned_data['lng']

def clean_lat(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['lat'] == 0.0:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your full story")
    # Always return the cleaned data    
    return self.cleaned_data['lat']     



def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    return cleaned_data
```

Here's my view

```
def test(request):
ctxt = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubmitForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data 
        if form.is_valid():
            lat1 = form.cleaned_data['lat']
            lng1 = form.cleaned_data['lng']
            # title1 = form.cleaned_data['title']
            titlepost = form.cleaned_data['title']
            story1 = form.cleaned_data['story']
            ctxt = {'titlehere':titlepost}
            catid = "test1234"
            cat = Category(category=catid)
            cat.full_clean()
            cat.save()
            marker = Marker(lat=lat1, lng=lng1,category=cat, title=titlepost, story=story1)
            marker.full_clean()
            marker.save()
            return render_to_response('home.html', ctxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request))          

        else:
            return render_to_response('test.html', ctxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request))          
else:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        form = SubmitForm()
        latest_marks = Marker.objects.all().order_by('-submitted')[0:10]
        ctxt = {
        'marks':latest_marks,
        'now':now.date(),
        'form': form,
        }

        return render_to_response('test.html', ctxt, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

For some reason each time i send the form I get this error message

Not really sure what going on. Still pretty new to Django. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: add in colons I was missing. Error still consists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some colons after your if statements in the clean methods of your form.

Comment: Change the error messages for lat/lon clean methods so you can at least hone in on which is the problem.

Comment: I changed the error messages but I don't know where to look for them. When the form doesn't validate it sends me to an other page with no data about the previous page

Comment: In general, if the form is invalid, you'll want to render the same page w/ the form. You're returning the rendered 'test.html' which does not have `form` in the context. Try adding `form` to it before rendering, and depending how you're outputting the form, it will probably show validation errors.

Comment: I suggest re-reading the Django tutorials, especially the ones involving forms. There are a lot of trivial mistakes happening and investing more time studying your own code and comparing with others should eventually lead to your solution. Stack Overflow is a great site for solving problems, but developers still need solid debugging skills on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using [Modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) ?

You can simplify your code just by using a modelform for Marker model (less code duplication, less code in general to create the model ...)

FYI:
You can send the min_length to CharField and get the len() validation for free :)

```
class SubmitForm(forms.Form):
     title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, min_length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason each time i send the form I get this error message

I can't see the error!
But I tried this and it works ok.

```
import math
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, min_length=4)
    story = forms.CharField(max_length=3000, min_length=4)
    lat = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)
    lng = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)

    def clean_lat(self):
        lat = self.cleaned_data['lat']
        if math.ceil(float(lat)) <= 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your full story")
        return self.cleaned_data['lat']

    def clean_lng(self):
        lng = self.cleaned_data['lng']
        if math.ceil(float(lng)) <= 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your full story")
        return self.cleaned_data['lng']
```

Comment: Still no luck with trying that. Thanks for trying though.